# How to merge those columns in mysql or should I use another join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I'm tring to get a specifed information from database. I manage to do something like this but I don't know how instead of `weapon, armor, etc` merge it into one column named `items`

```
SELECT char_name
     , obj_Id
     , items.item_id
     , weapon.name as weapon
     , armor.name as armor
     , etcitem.name as etc
  FROM characters 
  join items 
    on characters.obj_Id = items.owner_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN weapon 
    ON items.item_id = weapon.item_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN armor 
    ON items.item_id = armor.item_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN etcitem 
    ON items.item_id = etcitem.item_id;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT char_name, obj_Id, items.item_id,
       coalesce(weapon.name, armor.name, etcitem.name) as item_name
. . .
```

The `COALESCE()` function returns the first non-null expression in a list.

**Syntax**

`COALESCE(expr1, expr2, ...., expr_n)`